# UserControl: how to convert dependency properties and bind to the result

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls

I have a XAML UserControl, a combination of a Label, a TextBox and a ComboBox.
In the textbox I type a double value, which must be adjusted with a factor determined by my choice in the ComboBox. Always !
(In fact a unit conversion operation: meters to kilometers, feet to centimeters, etc.)
That way, I will always have consistent SI units "inside" the program
The logical place to do that would be inside the UserControl's code-behind.
Therefor I define a Dep Prop InternalValue, which will contain the adjusted value of the textbox. 
I need to be able to bind to that DP.
I tried to do something like the code below, but that won't fly: I get the indicated compile error in TextChanged.
How can I do what I want?

```
        public string  TBText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TBTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TBTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TBTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TBText", typeof(string), typeof(UCInputField), new PropertyMetadata( new PropertyChangedCallback(TextChanged)));

    private static void TextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        InternalValue = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue) * factor; // error: an object reference is required.

    }

    public double InternalValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(InternalValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InternalValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty InternalValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InternalValue", typeof(double), typeof(UCInputField));


    public DimPostfix CBSelectedItem
    {
        get { return (DimPostfix)GetValue(CBSelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CBSelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CBSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CBSelectedItem", typeof(DimPostfix), typeof(UCInputField),new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(UnitChanged)));

    static double factor;
    private static void UnitChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        factor = (e.NewValue as DimPostfix).Factor;
    }
```

And here is the UserControl:

```
    <UserControl
    x:Class="MyProgram.Views.UCInputField"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="45"
    d:DesignWidth="250"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label      
            Content="{Binding LBContent}"
            Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle1}" />
        <TextBox
            x:Name="TB"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Text="{Binding TBText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ComboBox
            x:Name="CBBox"
            Width="70"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CBUnit}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding CBSelectedItem}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

And the control will be used like this:

```
<ip:UCInputField
  CBSelectedItem="{Binding .....}"
  CBUnit="{Binding ....}"
  LBContent="Length"
  InternalValue="{Binding ...}"
  TBText="{Binding Path=Ucl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `TextChanged`is a static method. So it needs a reference to an instance of your User-Control if you want to change properties there.
One of the method parameters is of the type `DependencyObject`which is the object that owns the dependency-property that has been changed and can be casted into your User-Control.

```
private static void TextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = (UCInputField)d; //This is the reference that is needed
        myControl.InternalValue = Convert.ToDouble(e.NewValue) * factor; //You can user factor since it is static
    }
```